# Session Handling in PHP 5

Tags: php, session, destroy

i've a problem with php session handling that i can't explain to myself.
I'm studying php from scratch, and i can't figure out how to mantain a session live:

This is my index page, where a user can login or register to the database visiting the right page, and then come back to see if he's logged in:

Code:

```
Index

    <?php session_start(); ?>

     <a href="register.php" target="_self"> Register </a> 

     <a href="login.php" target="_self"> Login </a>


 <?php

if(isset($_SESSION['login']))
    {
        echo "Logged as: ".$_SESSION['nlogin'];

?>
     <form method="post" action="<?php unset($_SESSION['login']) ?>">
     <input type="button" name="logOut" value="LogOut" />
     </form>

<?php
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Please Register or Login";
    }
    ?>
```

In fact this work, because when i come back from login.php it says, "Logged as: Admin"

But when i click on the link to get the login page, or register page again from the index page, i should get the same message, "Logged as...", but the session appear to be closed instead. :(

here's login.php:

```
<?php


session_start(); 

include "dbConnect.php";

if(isset($_SESSION['login']))
    {
        echo "Logged as: ".$_SESSION['nlogin']; // IT NEVER SHOW THIS MESSAGE
    }

if(isset($_POST['submit']) &&(trim($_POST['submit']) == "Login"))
    {
        if(!isset($_POST['user']) || $_POST['user']=="")
        {
            echo "Attenzione inserire l'username.";
        }
        elseif(!isset($_POST['pwd'])||$_POST['pwd']=="")
        {
            echo "Attenzione inserire la password.";
        }
        else
        {
            $u = trim(filter_var($_POST['user'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
            $u = str_replace(" ","_",$u);
            $p = trim(filter_var($_POST['pwd'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
            $p = sha1($p);

            $istance = new dbHandle;
            $istance->connect(); 
            $data = $istance->query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username_login = '$u' AND password_login = '$p'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($data) == 0)
            {
                echo "Failed";


                echo "<a href='index.php' target='_self'> Go Back </a>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Logged";
                $res = $istance->getdata($data);
                $_SESSION['login'] = $res->id_login;
                $_SESSION['nlogin'] = $res->username_login; 



                echo "<a href='index.php' target='_self'> Go Back </a>";

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
        Login


        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            ...
                   <input name="user" type="text" size="20" required="required"/>
            ...
                   <input name="pwd" type="password" size="20" required="required"/>
            ...
                   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>  
        </form>


         <form method="post" action="<?php unset($_SESSION['login']) ?>">
         <input type="button" name="logOut" value="LogOut" />
         </form>

  <?php
    }
    $istance->disconnect();
?>
```

When i come back using the link above "Go Back" to the index page, it shows Logged as...
but when i come back here again, it does not.

So i assume my session were destroyed automatically?  but why?

Thanks, i appreciate your help.

I forget to say that PHP.ini has

> session.cookie_lifetime

set to "0"

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `unset($_SESSION['login'])` many times. It removes your login:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php unset($_SESSION['login']) ?>">
```

Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="button" name="logOut" value="LogOut" />
</form>

<? if (isset($_REQUEST['logOut'])){ session_destroy(); } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, i've figured out that the form action <br/> `form method="post" action="<?php unset($_SESSION['login'])..` were giving the problem. PHP interpreter used to unset the 'login' value stored in the session array every time. Thanks very much! i was getting mad!

Comment: Nice to hear. You know you should accept one of the answers and you can upvote answers you like. This will motivate users to help you and others ;)

Comment: I can't upvote right now, since more reputation, still long way ahead! but thank's anyway!

Comment: I upvoted you a little so you get there fast ;) But you should be able to accept answers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

unset the session like below

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['logOut']))
{
   unset($_SESSION['login']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You check for `if(isset($_SESSION['login']))`.
If that results in `true`, you do `<form method="post" action="<?php unset($_SESSION['login']) ?>">`

Note the `unset($_SESSION['login'])` part - after that, `if(isset($_SESSION['login']))` will return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Session overview :

```
<?php
// Always Start our session
session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] = 'Saurabh Singh'; 

$username =  $_SESSION['username'];

echo $username;

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    Do your action
}
else
{
    echo "Please Register or Login";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the session has been destroyed!
I would start by first removing all the empty lines between the opening tags for php and the
    session_start().
Test it again and you could add the line 
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
below the session_start to see if any error messages are echo(ed) back to you.
In your PHP.ini what 
    session.cookie_lifetime = 0 
means is that the session remain active so long as the browser stays open. It's only destroyed when the browser is closed.
I hope this helps